# Special polish characters not displayed properly

Tags: php, mysql, forms, encoding

When a user enters a postal code, we display location, unfortunately polish characters are not displayed correctly.

**Example:**

User enters `50-001` and it should display **Wrocław, Dolnośląskie**, but it shows up as **WrocÃ…â€šaw, DolnoÃ…â€ºlÃ„â€¦skie**

Does anyone know how to get this to work or what the problem is?

Comment: What character encoding are you using?

Comment: Are they saved into a database? Is that Database set to be UTF-8, or is it using something else?

Comment: Yes, saved into the db... utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

You have to also tell PDO or MySQLi to use UTF8:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=whatever;charset=utf8', $user, $pass);
```

or

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")
```

Answer (score 0):

Before any query you could run:

```
query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Or set it in an insert, if its only one field:

```
some_chinese_column = _utf8 "鬼佬"
```